# Can I link Trello boards to create a 'global view' of my boards

Tags: trello, trello-organization

Is there a way to view cards from all my Trello boards on one *summary* board.

The reason to do this: I'd like to give different team members access to different boards, however I'd like to have a single board from which I can access all of them - giving me a global view of what is happening.

I can ensure all boards have the same list names, to make it work. Is this possible directly, or is there a way to get a similar result.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can [with the Unito power up](https://blog.trello.com/trello-unito-power-up):

> The Unito Power-Up lets you sync data such as descriptions, labels, lists, checklists, Custom Fields, comments, due dates, members, attachments, and more. Teams receive real-time updates on what’s happening in multiple boards — without ever having to leave their own. The best part: You can control exactly what information gets synced by using the filters.